# Rails server command not working (other commands, as well)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm in the very first part of building a rails app and I can't get the command

```
rails server
```

to work, or really any other rails command. Whenever I attempt a rails command I get the help screen like this:

```
$rails server
Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]

 Options:
-r, [--ruby=PATH]              # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice                                   # Default: /home/sgallagher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-    p290/bin/ruby
-b, [--builder=BUILDER]        # Path to a application builder (can be a filesystem path or URL)
-m, [--template=TEMPLATE]      # Path to an application template (can be a filesystem path or URL)
[--skip-gemfile]           # Don't create a Gemfile
      [--skip-bundle]            # Don't run bundle install
    -G, [--skip-git]               # Skip Git ignores and keeps
```

and so on (it gives me the same "rails new" command no matter what command I put in)...

Any ideas on what might be missing in my system or why these commands aren't responding? Thanks

P.S. Another peculiar thing is when I created this app, initially, I used the command:

```
rails new first_app
```

This actually created two apps: one called 'new' and another called 'first_app'. It also didn't create a default Gemfile.

I am running Rails 3.1.0 and Ruby 1.9.2. on Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: I had this issue, `bundle exec rails server` worked for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may have installed Rails 3.1.0 but as forresty mentioned, I don't believe your path is using it.

I'd strongly recommend [rvm](http://beginrescueend.com/) (assuming you're not using it).  It will avoid problems down the road and it's easy to set up!

**EDIT**

It's possible that it's still trying to use your system rails.

`rvm use 1.9.2` then just do `gem install rails`, no `sudo`.  See if that works.  RVM  uses your profile to store all of its gems, my guess is when you type `rails`, it's using the system one.  To confirm this, type `which rails` and I'd guess it won't be under `~/.rvm/...`.

make sure you 
`echo '[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function' >> ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: I actually am using rvm ( just installed it yesterday) but I had been using Ruby 1.8.8 for a couple months before then, I'm wondering if the switch to rvm has anything to do with the weirdness I was seeing...

Comment: Edit above.  When you switched to RVM, RVM is keeping its own gem cache for each version of ruby you want. This means you'd have to reinstall all gems you had before under the proper RVM ruby or it wouldn't recognize them.  When doing so, you most likely don't want to use `sudo gem install` as this will install it to the system install of ruby (since you're `root`).  By doing simply `gem install`, it will keep it within your profile and the appropriate rvm.

Comment: I had ran 'which rails' prior to posting the question, and you're right, it wasn't from the rvm path. I'm a bit confused cause I have all these gems in sudo and then almost no local gems and I keep bouncing back and forth not sure of where my system is going to get the gems.... Now I just checked, and it is indeed coming from the rvm path and now working just fine (with the exception that I had to add the node.js gem to get webrick to work). Thanks, Kristian.

Comment: NP, read up on how RVM works a bit and you'll be glad  you switched over sooner than later!

Answer (score 14):

I was just having this problem. Make sure you are actually in the directory of your rails app whenever you execute the 'rails server' command. I wasn't in the dir. Dumb mistake but, it happens...

Answer (score 1):

It seems your are using an older version of Rails.

Try running `rails -v` and `which rails`

Comment: I was actually using Rails 3.1.0, which, I think in the latest one... This problem went away, I'm not too sure why...I did end up having to install node.js to ultimately get it to work, though

Comment: Rails 3.1 needs a JavaScript engine to compile the assets. It's new and the reason why you have to install node.js or therubyracer before launching your server for the first time

Answer (score 0):

For me `rails new "first_app"` produced these files:

```
create
create README.md
create Rakefile
create .ruby-version
create config.ru
create .gitignore
create Gemfile
run git init from "."
```

and it seems that **git wasn't installed** so it didn't proceed with the creation of the rest of the files