# Rails Server command not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4.2

I'm a complete newbie, starting to read "Rails 4 In Action" (Manning title) and have just installed Ruby, Rails, Gems, node.js, etc (as instructed by the book).

When I run the command "rails server," I get a response that's a lot like the one in this question:[Rails server command not working (other commands, as well)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288392/rails-server-command-not-working-other-commands-as-well)

But none of the replies to that seem to shed much light on the cause of my problem.  Here are the versions of Ruby, Rails, etc. that I'm running:
 ruby 2.1.7p400 (2015-08-18 revision 51632) [i386-mingw32]
 Rails 4.2.1
 (Gem) 2.2.5
 (DevKit) [INFO] found RubyInstaller v2.1.7 at C:/Ruby21

I downloaded node.js from http://nodejs.org (v4.2.2 LTS for Windows 64-bit)

I tried to cut & paste the response that I got when I entered the rails server command, but this "question" form didn't accept its formatting.

### Any insights will be appreciated, thanks.

note that when I ran the Rails new command (rails new things_i_bought), I got this result:

```
    exist  
identical  README.rdoc
identical  Rakefile
identical  config.ru
identical  .gitignore
identical  Gemfile
    exist  app
identical  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
identical  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
identical  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
identical  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
identical  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
identical  app/assets/images/.keep
identical  app/mailers/.keep
identical  app/models/.keep
identical  app/controllers/concerns/.keep
identical  app/models/concerns/.keep
    exist  bin
identical  bin/bundle
identical  bin/rails
identical  bin/rake
identical  bin/setup
    exist  config
identical  config/routes.rb
identical  config/application.rb
identical  config/environment.rb
conflict  config/secrets.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `rails server -b $IP -p $PORT`?

This guide helped me a lot, I hope it will be useful:
https://www.railstutorial.org/book/beginning

Comment: I will look at that guide. Thanks.